# Нахождение цифры на k -ой позиции в произведении двух натуральных чисел, состоящих из одних единиц

Tags: python

Закономерность произведений чисел, состоящих из единиц проста:
в числе будет сначала от 1 до максимальной цифры, затем повторяется макс.цифра, пока длинна числа не будет равна длине наибольшего числа, там опять будет от 1 до макс.цифры только в обратном порядке
максимальная цифра в числе- это длина самого мелкого числа
к примеру 111 * 11111 = 1233321
написал я код, но он не работает (точнее не со семи числами).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка?

```
n,m,k = map(int,input().split())

mini = min(n,m)
maxi = max(n,m)
if mini <= k <= maxi:
    print(mini)
else:
    stroka = ''
    for i in range(mini-1):
        stroka += str(i)
    if k > mini:
         k -= maxi
         mini = stroka[::-1]
    print(stroka[k-1])
```

Comment: Такое впечатление, что на каких-то курсах выдали задание и теперь все тут спрашивают, как его решить

Comment: самый простой вариант: умножьте, преобразуйте в строку, возьмите k-ый символ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я посмотрел твой код. Там много ошибок. например ты передаешь в range() число mini в результате ты получаешь последовательность длинной mini, а не длинной len(mini) к тому же твоя последовательность начиналась с 0. В общем я поправил все , но пришлось переписать многое.

```
n, m, k = map(int, input().split())

mini = min(n, m)
maxi = max(n, m)

stroka = '' # пустая строка
for i in range(1, len(str(mini)) + 1): 
    stroka += str(i) # создаем последовательность левой части числа от 1 до len(mini) + 1
d = stroka[-1] # берем последнюю цифру
r = stroka[-2::-1] # разворачиваем строку, без последней цифры, для правой части
stroka += d * (len(str(maxi)) - len(str(mini))) # добавляем нужное кол-во цифр в середину
stroka += r # добавлем правую часть, теперь stroka = произведению чисел в str формате
print(stroka[k-1]) # выводим цифру на искомой позиции
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно сделать:

```
def main(a:str, b:str, k:int):
    if a > b:
        a, b = b, a
    mult_len = len(a)+len(b)-1
    if k > mult_len:
        return
    if a == '1':
        return '1'
    res = ''.join([str(i) for i in range(1, len(a)+1)[::-1]])
    res_len = len(res)
    num = 1
    result = ''
    while res_len + len(result) < mult_len:
        result += str(num)
        if num < len(a):
            num += 1
    result += res
    return result[k-1]
    
a = input('Первое число: ')
b = input('Второе число: ')
k = int(input('Позиция: '))

print(main(a, b, k))
```